# Reading CSV file using PHP then create a table then search that table

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working to read a CSV file then create a table in HTML using that file then with that table I can search using Javascript.

My Code :

```js
$('#searchin').bind('input', function() { 
             document.getElementById("list").style.display="none";
             document.getElementById("btngo").disabled=true;

             if ($(this).val() != "") {
                      var list = document.getElementById("list").childNodes;
                      for (var i=0;i<list.length;i++) {
                                var values = list[i].innerHTML;
                                if(values){ 
                                         list[i].style.display="none";
                                         if (values.toLowerCase().includes($(this).val().toLowerCase()) == 1) {
                                                  document.getElementById("list").style.display="block";
                                                  list[i].style.display="block";
                                         }
                                         else {
                                                  list[i].style.display="none";
                                         }
                                 }
                      }
               }
});

$("#list tr").click(function() {
              document.getElementById("searchin").value=this.outerText;
              document.getElementById("list").style.display="none"; 
              document.getElementById("btngo").disabled=false;

              var link = $(this).attr("href");

              document.getElementById("btngo").addEventListener("click", function(){
                               window.open(link,'_self',false)
              })
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
</style>
<title>Index Page</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<label id="lblGreetings"></label>
<div class="navbar">
  <a class="active" href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Products
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="currency.php">Currency Exchange</a>
      <a href="#">Service 2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Contact Us
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#"><img alt="France Flag" src="french.png" width="20" height="20">Contactez-nous</a>
      <a href="#"><img alt="Egypt Flag" src="egypt.png" width="20" height="20">اتصل بنا</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="about.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-address-card"></i> About Us</a>
</div>
<p>The purpose of this site is to provide protective services and outline the powers of our super heroes and super villians</p>
<div id="search"> 
     <div id="container1"> 
          <input type="text" id="searchin" placeholder="Seacrh..."/> 
          <button id="btngo" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" disabled>Go</button> 
     </div> 
     <div id="container2"> 
            <table border="1" id="list"><tr><td>Item #</td><td>Name</td><td>Type</td><td>Make</td><td>Model</td><td>Brand</td><td>Description</td></tr><tr><td>100</td><td>Service One</td><td>Service</td><td>Casio</td><td>2020</td><td>Programming Consultation</td><td>1 hour of consulting on web design concepts</td></tr><tr><td>101</td><td>Service Two</td><td>Service</td><td>Casio</td><td>2020</td><td>Programming Consultation</td><td>5 hours of consulting on web design concepts</td></tr><tr><td>102</td><td>ProgCalc</td><td>Product</td><td>Casio</td><td>2020</td><td>Prgramming</td><td>Programmable calculator</td></tr><tr><td>103</td><td>ProgBook</td><td>Book</td><td>Casio</td><td>2020</td><td>O'Reilly</td><td>A book on web design concepts</td></tr><tr><td>104</td><td>Batman</td><td>Magazine</td><td>Casio</td><td>2020</td><td>Marval</td><td>Comic book about batman</td></tr><tr><td>105</td><td>Joker</td><td>Magazine</td><td>Casio</td><td>2020</td><td>Marval</td><td>Comic book about Joker</td></tr><tr><td>106</td><td>Lux</td><td>Magazine</td><td>Casio</td><td>2020</td><td>Marval</td><td>Comic book about Lux</td></tr><tr><td>107</td><td>Superman</td><td>Magazine</td><td>Casio</td><td>2020</td><td>Marval</td><td>Comic book about Superman</td></tr><tr><td>108</td><td>Teen Titans</td><td>Magazine</td><td>Casio</td><td>2020</td><td>Marval</td><td>Comic book about Teen Titans</td></tr><tr><td>109</td><td>Scarecrow</td><td>Magazine</td><td>Casio</td><td>2020</td><td>Marval</td><td>Comic book about Scarecrow</td></tr><tr><td>110</td><td>Bain</td><td>Magazine</td><td>Casio</td><td>2020</td><td>Marval</td><td>Comic book about Bain</td></tr><tr><td>111</td><td>Heliocopter </td><td>Machinery</td><td>Casio</td><td>2020</td><td>Marval</td><td>Heliocopter </td></tr><tr><td>112</td><td>Bat Mobile</td><td>Machinery</td><td>Casio</td><td>2020</td><td>Marval</td><td>The one and only bat mobile</td></tr><tr><td>113</td><td>Bat Jet</td><td>Machinery</td><td>Casio</td><td>2020</td><td>Marval</td><td>Jet for travelling across seas</td></tr></table>     
          </div>

     </div>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#searchin').on('input', function() {
    let val = $(this).val().trim().toLowerCase()
    if (val === '') $('#list tr:not(:first-child)').removeClass('hidden');
    else $('#list tr:not(:first-child)').addClass('hidden');
    $('#list tr:not(:first-child) td').each(function() {
      if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().includes(val)) $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('hidden')
    });
  });
</script>
<script>
  var myDate = new Date();
    var hrs = myDate.getHours();

    var greet;

    if (hrs < 6 && hrs <= 24)
        greet = 'Good Morning, you must be an early bird';
    else if (hrs < 12 && hrs >= 6)
        greet = 'Good Morning';
    else if (hrs >= 12 && hrs <= 18)
        greet = 'Good Afternoon';
    else if (hrs > 18 && hrs < 24)
        greet = 'Good Evening';
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

However I can see the Table, but not matter what I do, the table just stays the same. Unsearchable. Like a block of cement. As in the screenshot below.

The process will be that to import the CSV using PHP into a table, then using the table I can use javascript to search the table.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bR1CV.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please remove your PHP and replace it with the rendered HTML table data? There's no way we can help you if we don't have the table to test with.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: If you use PHP to generate the table you can, in the same process, generate a JSON object in Javascript and then search that - no?

Comment: The process has to be PHP generate Table > Search the table using Javascript

Comment: You can view source on your page and copy the rendered table's HTML.

Comment: Done. I added the Table.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this example. I wasnt sure what you were trying to accomplish with all your code, but I did understand you wanted to search the table rows. When the user types in the search box, the table:

- sets all tbody tr rows to hidden
- then it cycles through each tbody td. If the text inside is a match (even a partial match) it sets the parent tr to visible.
- we find the parent tr through $(this).closest('tr')
- we find the partial match with $(this).text().includes(str)
- we set the search string to lower case and the td text to lower case to rule out case sensitivity

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#searchin').on('input', function() {
    let val = $(this).val().trim().toLowerCase()
    if (val === '') $('#list tr:not(:first-child)').removeClass('hidden');
    else $('#list tr:not(:first-child)').addClass('hidden');
    $('#list tr:not(:first-child) td').each(function() {
      if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().includes(val)) $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('hidden')
    });
  });

  var myDate = new Date();
  var hrs = myDate.getHours();

  var greet;

  if (hrs < 6 && hrs <= 24)
    greet = 'Good Morning, you must be an early bird';
  else if (hrs < 12 && hrs >= 6)
    greet = 'Good Morning';
  else if (hrs >= 12 && hrs <= 18)
    greet = 'Good Afternoon';
  else if (hrs > 18 && hrs < 24)
    greet = 'Good Evening';

  $('lblGreetings').html(`<b>${greet}</b> and welcome to Encodedna.com!`);

});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<label id="lblGreetings"></label>
<div class="navbar">
  <a class="active" href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Products
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="currency.php">Currency Exchange</a>
      <a href="#">Service 2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Contact Us
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#"><img alt="France Flag" src="french.png" width="20" height="20">Contactez-nous</a>
      <a href="#"><img alt="Egypt Flag" src="egypt.png" width="20" height="20">اتصل بنا</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="about.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-address-card"></i> About Us</a>
</div>
<p>The purpose of this site is to provide protective services and outline the powers of our super heroes and super villians</p>
<div id="search">
  <div id="container1">
    <input type="text" id="searchin" placeholder="Seacrh..." />
    <button id="btngo" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" disabled>Go</button>
  </div>
  <div id="container2">
    <table>
      <table border="1" id="list">
        <tr>
          <td>Item #</td>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>Type</td>
          <td>Make</td>
          <td>Model</td>
          <td>Brand</td>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>100</td>
          <td>Service One</td>
          <td>Service</td>
          <td>Casio</td>
          <td>2020</td>
          <td>Programming Consultation</td>
          <td>1 hour of consulting on web design concepts</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>200</td>
          <td>Service two</td>
          <td>Thing</td>
          <td>Foo</td>
          <td>2022</td>
          <td>Bar</td>
          <td>Loresn ipsum</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Btw, I am a total newb

Comment: _it doesn't work on PHP_ - not sure why or why not. Do you get an error?

Comment: No, It just does nothing. The table will show, but will not search or hide it.

Comment: My php code doesn't produce tbody just tr and td

Comment: echo '<table border="1" id="list">';
foreach( $item as $row )
{
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach( $row as $key )
    {
        echo '<td>'.$key.'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';

Comment: Do I need to switch the function() to something else?

Comment: Do I need to put the PHP after the Javascript?

Comment: No. The php writes to the page first, then the javascript renders so do php first.

Comment: I added the full code in the HTML part. It shows the table, but won't react to the javascript.